# How does docker for windows decide what image to use

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have two build servers building docker containers, a Windows10-1709 OS and Server2016-LTS, they both build containers based on microsoft/dotnet-framework:latest

These containers are then deployed by our CD system to a test Server2016-LTS host.  The host is a VM and is restored to a checkpoint prior to each deployment.  The checkpoint has the latest microsoft/dotnet-framework:latest image pulled and stored in it, checkpoint was updated today.

When the container from Server2016-LTS build server deploys, it just pulls our part of the image and is up and running in under 60 seconds.

When the image from the Windows10-1709 build server deploys, it takes ~10 minutes to deploy an image that contains ~10Mb of code. It's pull a different base image (I'm assuming one based on 1709).  Once the pull completes, the image fails to run with the following error:

> 2018-02-15T23:15:57.3170769Z failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time="2018-02-15T23:15:48Z" level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) layerId=\\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\d7defcca1ec427b77fca7528840e442a596598002140b30afb4b5bb52311c8c6 flavour=1 folder=C:\Windows\TEMP\hcs025707919"
>
> 2018-02-15T23:15:57.3171830Z hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) layerId=\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\d7defcca1ec427b77fca7528840e442a596598002140b30afb4b5bb52311c8c6 flavour=1 folder=C:\Windows\TEMP\hcs025707919

My assumption was that all the Microsoft/dotnet-framework:latest images are LTS, and you have to specify 1709 to get that base.

So why do my two docker images, which both have the same FROM in their docker file, behave so differently?

Thanks.

Comment: could it be that the slow server uses a different docker registry?
is the final result from both server identical?

Comment: Look at docker image id for each image to verify if you got correct image

Comment: Both containers are in the same registry, it's an Azure Container Registry. When the slow image finally deploys, it will not start, fails with an error I've added to the question.

Comment: If I look in the repository for the images of the same Dockerfile built on a Server2016-LTS and Windows10-1709 , the base layers are different.  I was expecting the same base image in both images?

Comment: If you want consistency, don't use alias tags like "latest", use a tag that has a unique name per build (or to really be sure, use the sha256 value, which is what we do in our CD environment).

Comment: Totally agree and I do that for most things, what I'm stuck on is why building the same docker file on two different machines did not result in the same output, even after pulling the latest versions of everything local first.